# Express's compression doesn't work with EJS

Tags: typescript, express, ejs

I've created a class to represent my Express App. I've also generated a default HTML file as `index.ejs`. The problem is that when I use `compression()` and even `minify()` from `express-minify` it does not compress my HTML pages at all.

App class:

```
import { Express, json, urlencoded } from "express";
import helmet from "helmet";
import morgan from "morgan";
import compression from "compression";
import minify from "express-minify";
import { resolve } from "path";
import env from "./env";
import web from "../routes/web";
import api from "../routes/api";

export default class App {
  constructor(private expressInstance: Express) {
    this.setPort();
    this.setViewEngine("ejs");
    this.setViewPath(resolve(__dirname, "../views"));
    this.setMiddlewares();
    this.setRoutes();
  }

  private setPort(): void {
    this.expressInstance.set("port", parseInt(env("PORT") || "3000", 10));
    console.log("> Set the port to %s.", this.expressInstance.get("port"));
  }

  private setMiddlewares(): void {
    [
      compression(),
      minify(),
      json(),
      urlencoded({ extended: true }),
      helmet(),
      morgan(process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "combined" : "dev"),
    ].forEach((middleware) => {
      this.expressInstance.use(middleware);
      console.info('> Loaded middleware "%s".', middleware.name);
    });
  }

  private setViewEngine(viewEngine: string): void {
    this.expressInstance.set("view engine", viewEngine);
    console.info('> Set view engine to "%s".', viewEngine);
  }

  private setViewPath(viewPath: string): void {
    this.expressInstance.set("views", viewPath);
    console.log('> Set the view path to "%s".', viewPath);
  }

  private setRoutes(): void {
    this.expressInstance.use(web).use("/api", api);
  }

  public startApp(): void {
    this.expressInstance.listen(this.expressInstance.get("port"), () => {
      console.info(
        "> Application is running on port %s.",
        this.expressInstance.get("port")
      );
    });
  }
}
```

EJS file `index`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>test</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So, the [compression](https://www.npmjs.com/package/compression) module does transport level compression.  This will not be visible to you when looking at the received HTML file because it will be decompressed when you look at it.  You could see if it was active by looking at the headers that were used in transport.

Comment: Also, I would guess the `minify()` must run BEFORE compression().